Techniques for adaptive prediction with feedback in an evolving feature space
I am working on a prediction problem where the target variable  is drawn from a normal distribution, and the relationship between the continuous feature space  and  remains stable over time. However, the target values (e.g., mean and standard deviation) evolve over time in response to changes in the system. I do not have prior knowledge of the true target values in advance, so I am leveraging techniques such as online regression and reinforcement learning (RL) to iteratively adjust my predictions based on feedback.
The feedback mechanism only indicates whether my prediction was an overestimate or an underestimate, and this feedback is provided after a delay. The magnitude of error is unknown, and only directional feedback (over/under) is given. I am currently using an incremental approach where I update the predictions by adjusting them up or down based on the feedback.
I have two main questions regarding improving this approach:
(1) Improving Adaptive Adjustment Techniques:

I am currently using online regression and RL, where the feedback informs me whether to increment or decrement the prior prediction. Are there more advanced techniques I should explore for making more intelligent adjustments beyond simple increments/decrements? Specifically, are there approaches that allow for more nuanced adjustments when feedback is limited to over/under indications, and that could potentially lead to faster convergence or better predictions over time?

(2) Efficient Management of Adaptive Update Values:

To enhance my current approach, I have considered maintaining dynamic upper and lower bounds for the predictions, adjusting these bounds based on feedback (i.e., narrowing the range between the over/under estimates). Another strategy I’ve explored is using an exponentially weighted moving average (EWMA) of prior adjustments, where repeated underestimation leads to progressively larger corrections. However, managing these adjustments across a large feature space is computationally expensive.
My initial approach of mapping feature  to these update values (such as bounds or EWMA adjustments) using a dictionary became impractical as the feature space grew. I also attempted mapping these values to a regression model, but it did not perform well, likely due to the non-stationary nature of the updates.
Given that these adjustment values are not static targets but dynamically evolving based on feedback, what is the best way to manage or model them efficiently in a high-dimensional feature space? Are there more suitable strategies for adaptive updates in such a setting, possibly involving function approximation techniques or memory-efficient data structures?

